# How can I use mongodb to only allow one entry when multiple servers are accessing the database?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I have multiple "worker" servers processing jobs and accessing the same MongoDB database but I only want one message to be created and never allow two servers running the same job to create the same message.

When a message is sent, its `status` field is set to "sent" or if it's disabled it's set to "disabled".  So first it checks if there are any sent or disabled messages.  Then it creates a document with a `lockedAt` field set to the current time and checks if the same message has already been locked.  The reason I use the `lockedAt` field is so that if the job fails for some reason, it will allow the lock to expire and run again.

This seems to work most of the time but there are a few messages getting through if two "workers" run the same job within a few milliseconds so my logic isn't perfect but I can't figure out how duplicate messages are being created.

How can I use MongoDB to prevent the same job from running at the exact same time and creating the same message twice?

```
// Check if there is a locked message.
// insert a new message or update if one is found but return old message (or nothing if one didn't' exist)
const messageQuery = {
    listingID: listing._id,
    messageRuleID: messageRule._id,
    reservationID: reservation._id
};

let message = await Message.findOne({
    ...messageQuery,
    ...{status: {$in: ["disabled", "sent"]}}
});
// If message has been sent or is disabled don't continue
if (message) {
    return;
}

message = await Message.findOneAndUpdate(
    messageQuery,
    {
        listingID: listing._id,
        messageRuleID: messageRule._id,
        reservationID: reservation._id,
        lockedAt: moment().toDate() // Check out the message with the current date
    },
    {upsert: true}
);
// If no message is defined, then it's new and not locked, move on.
if (message) {
    // If message has been locked for less than X minutes don't continue
    const cutoff = moment().subtract(
        Config.messageSendLock.amount,
        Config.messageSendLock.unit
    );
    if (message.lockedAt && moment(message.lockedAt).isAfter(cutoff)) {
        // Put the last lock time back
        await Message.findOneAndUpdate(messageQuery, {lockedAt: message.lockedAt});
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: I had the same problem and use a similar solution. The job on one server is shifted by 1-2 Minutes, by this I prevent such clashes.

Comment: What are you setting `_id` as?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit I have thousands of jobs and although I would rather the same job isn't to run at the same time I don't have control over that.

Comment: @Yahya, the `_id` is set by MongoDB.  It's something similar to this `5fe3543b4477fe13efa83286`.  Why do you ask?

Comment: `_id` is set by the driver, not MongoDB. Also, you need to do all operations in one call. Think about adding more complexity in your first request or do an aggregate update if you are on 4.2+

Comment: Since you will only have one document in that collection, make sure all those fields are indexed.

Comment: @Yahya thanks.  Yes. I think that's the correct solution.  How do I do all the operations in one call?

Answer (score 1):

It's much simpler than that. In Mongo [write operations are atomic on document level](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/write-operations-atomicity/#atomicity).

All you need to do is to define a unique key for your message.

Assuming the key is:

```
const messageId = {
    listingID: listing._id,
    messageRuleID: messageRule._id,
    reservationID: reservation._id
};
```

Then all you need is 2 write queries. First one is the "insert" half of your upsert:

```
try {
    await Message.create(messageId);
} catch (err) {
    if (err.code !== '11000') {  // ignore duplicate key error
        throw err
    }
}
```

This is idempotent and can be executed by multiple workers at the same time. The result is always the same - exactly 1 document in the collection.

This index can be defined [on schema level](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#indexes) as following:

```
Message.index({
        listingID: 1,
        messageRuleID: 1,
        reservationID: 1
}, { unique: true })
```

**IMPORTANT**: Ensure you not only define the unique index on your model but also the index was applied to the collection on db side. Mongoose has some optimisations and does not always apply indexes. Otherwise the code above will create duplicates. The relevant piece from the [mongoose documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#indexes):

> When your application starts up, Mongoose automatically calls createIndex for each defined index in your schema. Mongoose will call createIndex for each index sequentially, and emit an 'index' event on the model when all the createIndex calls succeeded or when there was an error. While nice for development, it is recommended this behavior be disabled in production since index creation can cause a significant performance impact. Disable the behavior by setting the autoIndex option of your schema to false, or globally on the connection by setting the option autoIndex to false.

The second query is the "update" part of your upsert:

```
const cutoff = moment().subtract(
    Config.messageSendLock.amount,
    Config.messageSendLock.unit
);
    

message = await Message.findOneAndUpdate(
    {
        ...messageId,
        status: {$nin: ["disabled", "sent"]},
        $or: [
            { lockedAt: {$exists: false} }, 
            { lockedAt: {$lte: cutoff}}
        ]
    },
    { lockedAt: moment().toDate() }
);

// If no message is defined, then it's either sent, disabled, or is locked
if (!message) {
    return
}
```

Running this query from multiple workers at the same time will result with a [queue of IX locks](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/faq/concurrency/) on the matching document on the db side. The first one will add/update the `lockedAt` field and return the document to your worker. All consecutive queries won't match the filter and return nothing.

Comment: Thanks!  How do I define a unique key?  Is it possible to define a unique key event though thousands of entries already exist in the collection?

Comment: But of course. You can add and remove indexes from existing collection. Please see my updates on how to define indexes in Mongoose schema. Also ensure you read the quoted excerpt from the documentation. Considering number of questions about mongoose indexes on Stackoverflow its behaviour is not exactly intuitive.

Comment: Thanks for explaining that about unique indexes, I had exactly that issue with a different project where I added it to the code but it didn't seem to take effect.  I guess I never verified it was saved to the database.  One last question.  It's possible that some message documents have the same `{listingID, messageRuleID, reservationID}` but different `status` fields.  Is there any way to take that into account?

Comment: Yeah, it's the most critical part of the technique. That's why I started the answer with "All **you** need to do is to define a unique key for your message". 
It's something unique to your application and is tightly coupled with business logic which is apparently not that obvious from the question. I assumed standard FSM with status representing current state. I'm afraid you will need to elaborate how it works if you need help defining the index.

Comment: Alex, do you have a second to look at the question linked below?  It's related this question but I seem to have found a way to get around your lock code using multiple servers connecting to the same database at the same time. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67375281/how-to-prevent-multiple-documents-from-being-added-to-mongodb-database

Answer (score 0):

Create a separate collection, say `jobs`.

Whenever you want to start processing a document, insert into `jobs` with _id equal to the document _id.

When processing is done, remove the job.

Set the equivalent of `lockedAt` on the job.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I'm not sure how this is any better than what I'm using now.  I need some way to guarantee that if 2 jobs are run at the same time they can't create duplicate `message` documents