# How to prevent multiple documents from being added to mongodb database

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have multiple "worker" servers running jobs and sometimes more than one server will run the same job.  I only want one server to be able to complete the job so I added the following index to a `Message` schema to prevent duplicate messages:

```
const Message = new Schema(
    {
        accountID: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Account", required: true},
        listingID: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Listing", required: true},
        messageRuleID: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "MessageRule", required: true},
        reservationID: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Reservation", required: true},
        lockedAt: Date,
        status: String
    },
    {timestamps: true}
);

Message.index(
    {
        listingID: 1,
        messageRuleID: 1,
        reservationID: 1
    },
    {unique: true, name: "Message_index_0"}
);
```

Then I use the following code to create and lock a message to prevent a message from sending twice:

```
const messageQuery = {
    accountID: "604f9355eeab332490184532",
    listingID: "604f9358be89f997345b238d",
    messageRuleID: "607d44e75d54c700041f38e1",
    reservationID: "605118b7694b9765f49787e1"
};

async function start() {
    const time = moment().toDate();
    try {
        const message = await Message.create(messageQuery);
        console.log("CREATED A MESSAGE", message._id);
    } catch (error) {
        if (error.code !== 11000) {
            // ignore duplicate key error
            throw error;
        } else {
            console.log("DUPLICATE MESSAGE");
        }
    }

    const cutoff = moment().subtract(
        Config.messageSendLock.amount,
        Config.messageSendLock.unit
    );
    const message = await Message.findOneAndUpdate(
        {
            ...messageQuery,
            status: {$nin: ["disabled", "sent"]},
            $or: [
                {lockedAt: {$exists: false}},
                {lockedAt: null},
                {lockedAt: {$lte: cutoff}}
            ]
        },
        {lockedAt: moment().toDate()}
    );

    // If no message is defined, then it's either sent, disabled, or is locked
    if (!message) {
        console.log("Existing, message is either sent, disabled, or is locked");
        return;
    }
    await Message.findOneAndUpdate(messageQuery, {
        status: "sent",
        $unset: {lockedAt: ""} // Not sure this is needed
    });
    console.log("SEND MESSAGE", time, message._id);
}
```

This code works great if I put it in a forEach loop and run it a hundred times but when I run it from multiple servers, each with its own connection to the database, some of the servers think they are creating a document and are able to send the message twice.

I've been able to reproduce this issue by using [throng](https://github.com/hunterloftis/throng), see below:

```
throng({
    worker: start,
    count: 50,
    lifetime: Infinity
});
```

When I run the above code this is the console output:

```
CREATED A MESSAGE 60905845a3bd3922c477182f
DUPLICATE MESSAGE
Existing, message is either sent, disabled, or is locked
SEND MESSAGE 2021-05-03T20:08:37.257Z 60905845a3bd3922c477182f
CREATED A MESSAGE 60905845a3caa422c6bbb74d
Existing, message is either sent, disabled, or is locked
CREATED A MESSAGE 6090584561583c22c8752b61
CREATED A MESSAGE 6090584529dcee22c733a1eb
Existing, message is either sent, disabled, or is locked
Existing, message is either sent, disabled, or is locked
CREATED A MESSAGE 6090584569c22d22c216733a
DUPLICATE MESSAGE
Existing, message is either sent, disabled, or is locked
Existing, message is either sent, disabled, or is locked
DUPLICATE MESSAGE
CREATED A MESSAGE 609058451bb43d22cc5519d5
DUPLICATE MESSAGE
Existing, message is either sent, disabled, or is locked
SEND MESSAGE 2021-05-03T20:08:37.765Z 609058451bb43d22cc5519d5
DUPLICATE MESSAGE
DUPLICATE MESSAGE
Existing, message is either sent, disabled, or is locked
Existing, message is either sent, disabled, or is locked
Existing, message is either sent, disabled, or is locked
CREATED A MESSAGE 609058469c84e322cd30b326
Existing, message is either sent, disabled, or is locked
CREATED A MESSAGE 60905846b2ab3e22d215792f
DUPLICATE MESSAGE
DUPLICATE MESSAGE
Existing, message is either sent, disabled, or is locked
SEND MESSAGE 2021-05-03T20:08:38.461Z 60905846b2ab3e22d215792f
CREATED A MESSAGE 60905846697d5922d02fb377
Existing, message is either sent, disabled, or is locked
SEND MESSAGE 2021-05-03T20:08:38.466Z 60905846697d5922d02fb377
DUPLICATE MESSAGE
CREATED A MESSAGE 60905846a6c30622d6350eea
CREATED A MESSAGE 609058462b0ce822d9d9dca1
Existing, message is either sent, disabled, or is locked
SEND MESSAGE 2021-05-03T20:08:38.784Z 60905846a6c30622d6350eea
SEND MESSAGE 2021-05-03T20:08:38.968Z 609058462b0ce822d9d9dca1
CREATED A MESSAGE 60905846e61d3e22dbe1542a
CREATED A MESSAGE 60905846065b3822d428f2c9
CREATED A MESSAGE 6090584708f85722e0df9cd2
CREATED A MESSAGE 6090584734d99922dd612ae3
Existing, message is either sent, disabled, or is locked
Existing, message is either sent, disabled, or is locked
Existing, message is either sent, disabled, or is locked
Existing, message is either sent, disabled, or is locked
CREATED A MESSAGE 60905847fd807822dffc23f2
DUPLICATE MESSAGE
DUPLICATE MESSAGE
CREATED A MESSAGE 609058470a07ff22daafe0db
DUPLICATE MESSAGE
DUPLICATE MESSAGE
DUPLICATE MESSAGE
DUPLICATE MESSAGE
DUPLICATE MESSAGE
Existing, message is either sent, disabled, or is locked
CREATED A MESSAGE 60905847abbbe522eac8be2e
DUPLICATE MESSAGE
SEND MESSAGE 2021-05-03T20:08:39.517Z 609058470a07ff22daafe0db
DUPLICATE MESSAGE
Existing, message is either sent, disabled, or is locked
Existing, message is either sent, disabled, or is locked
Existing, message is either sent, disabled, or is locked
Existing, message is either sent, disabled, or is locked
Existing, message is either sent, disabled, or is locked
Existing, message is either sent, disabled, or is locked
CREATED A MESSAGE 60905847d5283d22f3aa6239
Existing, message is either sent, disabled, or is locked
Existing, message is either sent, disabled, or is locked
Existing, message is either sent, disabled, or is locked
SEND MESSAGE 2021-05-03T20:08:39.529Z 60905847d5283d22f3aa6239
Existing, message is either sent, disabled, or is locked
CREATED A MESSAGE 6090584717434e22e3634596
DUPLICATE MESSAGE
DUPLICATE MESSAGE
DUPLICATE MESSAGE
DUPLICATE MESSAGE
Existing, message is either sent, disabled, or is locked
DUPLICATE MESSAGE
DUPLICATE MESSAGE
DUPLICATE MESSAGE
DUPLICATE MESSAGE
Existing, message is either sent, disabled, or is locked
DUPLICATE MESSAGE
Existing, message is either sent, disabled, or is locked
SEND MESSAGE 2021-05-03T20:08:39.573Z 6090584717434e22e3634596
DUPLICATE MESSAGE
Existing, message is either sent, disabled, or is locked
Existing, message is either sent, disabled, or is locked
DUPLICATE MESSAGE
Existing, message is either sent, disabled, or is locked
Existing, message is either sent, disabled, or is locked
Existing, message is either sent, disabled, or is locked
Existing, message is either sent, disabled, or is locked
DUPLICATE MESSAGE
Existing, message is either sent, disabled, or is locked
Existing, message is either sent, disabled, or is locked
Existing, message is either sent, disabled, or is locked
```

You can see it's somehow able to bypass the checks and send the message multiple times.  Is there any way to prevent the message from sending twice?

#### Update:

Connection to db:

```
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.connect(Config.uristring, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useCreateIndex: true,
    useFindAndModify: false,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
});
```

Database settings:

Hosted on `Mongodb Atlas`

Db Version: `4.2.13`

Replica Set - 3 nodes

"mongodb://abc:def@ghi-00.mongodb.net:27017,ghi-01.mongodb.net:27017,ghi-02.mongodb.net:27017/jkl?ssl=true&replicaSet=ghi-00&authSource=admin";

#### Update 2:

I added a `sleep()` function between the `message.create()` code and the `findOneAndUpdate()` code that locks the message. I made each one sleep for a random amount of time from 2 to 7 seconds and seemed to fix the issue most of the time.  It's just a hack and not a good long-term solution.

`await sleep(Math.floor(Math.random() * 50) * 100 + 2000);`

```
function sleep(ms) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(resolve, ms);
    });
}
```

Comment: I can't see where it sent a message multiple times to be honest. The log has 20 unique messages created and 9 unique messages sent. What exactly makes you thinking it sends duplicates?

Comment: Thanks for looking at this.  I'm passing in the same `listingID`, `messageRuleID` and `reservationID` in `messageQuery` so it should only send one message but like you said, it's sending the same message 9 times.  Does that make sense?  I really appreciate the help.

Comment: Ah, so it is the same query and you expect to see no more than 1 "CREATED A MESSAGE" and "SEND MESSAGE", yes? May I ask how documents with "CREATED A MESSAGE" ids look like in the database? Do they indeed have identical values in the Message_index_0 fields?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.  Good question.  When I look for those ids in the database they don't exist (except for 1 of them).  It's almost as if, the database realizes it shouldn't have created them and deleted them but by then it's too late and the duplicate message is sent.

Comment: Could you describe the database set up and connection settings? Version, number of shards, replica set, read preferences, write concerns? The ID is generated cliendside by the driver and I could imagine it failed to raise the error for some reason, but having the same ID in the findOneAndUpdate response means the data comes from mongodb. I'll try to reproduce it.

Comment: @AlexBlex I wasn't sure how to answer the read preferences and write concerns question but updated the question with the answer to the other questions.  I really appreciate your help.

Comment: If there are no "readPreference=" in the Config.uristring it is default "primary". Write concern is set per write operation. IIRC it's 1 by default. I assume it's a single shard and is a dedicated tier m10 or higher.

Comment: uristring doesn't have `readPreference=` (I added the uristring to the question).  Yes, it's on m10.

Comment: I must be missing something but I couldn't reproduce it. The whole code I used for testing, package.json and output is here https://gist.github.com/blex18/0ff46b4931ef965e1ef62a60a5704a68  Could you try this script on your environment to confirm it still inserts duplicates. If so I'll need package-lock and details of the OS - type and version.

Comment: @AlexBlex, you're right.  Your version works great.  I made some changes and was able to reproduce my issue using your code but I think it's because I'm configuring MongoDB incorrectly.  Here are the changes I made to reproduce the issue.  It might be because I'm not waiting for the `db.once('open'` event?  I'm worried now that my whole project is initializing mongodb incorrectly.   https://gist.github.com/wootwoot1234/49cb7d082850d93f8cd03da164644cfb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies somewhere in mongoose compatibility with throng.

It fires new "connect" event for each "thread" and you delete the document on connect https://gist.github.com/wootwoot1234/49cb7d082850d93f8cd03da164644cfb#file-index-js-L100:

```
db.once('open', async function() {
  await Message.deleteOne(messageQuery); // <=== remove it from here to fix the problem
  throng({
    worker: start,
    count: 50,
    lifetime: Infinity
  });
});
```

It must be because of the way throng isolates global variables between threads, connection pool in particular.  By default mongoose connection pool is 5, which means there are no more than 5 connections to the database at a time. The driver keeps them open and reuse to save on connection cost.

If you check Atlas connections monitoring you will see some extra 100 connections when you run this script.